# android app crash when included code after toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml

when I clear my **content of homepage xml** file,  apps running successfully. But when I add content again, My apps crash.

##### activity_home_page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_home_page"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home_page"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home_page"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

### app_bar_homepage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomePage">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BjkuApps.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.BjkuApps.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home_page"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/loginMoreFabIdForHomePage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="@string/login_for_more"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/loginForMoreButton"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

#### content_of_homepage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home_page">

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipperID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.4"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6.6"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/home_item_recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I clear "**content of homepage**" code, this apps successfully running like now...
Image link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qkE9YDuOs1V2Mq7ma4Cj-7khEO7sGsCV/view?usp=sharing

#### theme.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.BjkuApps" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/default_Color_main</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.BjkuApps.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.BjkuApps">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.BjkuApps.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.BjkuApps.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

#### android manifast.file

```
<activity
    android:name=".HomePage"
    android:exported="false"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_home_page"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.BjkuApps.NoActionBar" />
```

Comment: Please add the error message

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.BjkuApps.android/com.BjkuApps.android.HomePage}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070093

     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070093
        at com.BjkuApps.android.HomePage.imageSlider(**HomePage.java:176**)
        at com.BjkuApps.android.HomePage.onCreate(**HomePage.java:92**)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Apps crash, When I add kind of widget in **content_of_homepage.xml** file.
But when I clear this, application work....

**content_of_homepage.xml** is part of **App_bar_homePage.xml** && "app_bar_homepage.xml** part of  "activity_home_page.xml**

>> (There is code above.)

Comment: please tell me, Are there any problem of  **content_of_homepage.xml** layout?
[ I'm new of android ]

Comment: Please check ViewFlipper  in home page xml is properly implemented or not.

Comment: **ViewFlipper** section included in **content_of_homepage.xml** is given above.
I'm new in android, Please see this and tell me whats problem in here....

Answer (score 0):

change this code in `themes.xml`

```
<style name="Theme.BjkuApps" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

to this:

```
<style name="Theme.BjkuApps" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

this may help you

Comment: Change...but no work

When I clear **content_of_homepage.xml** this working

Answer (score 0):

Your layout file name is `content_of_homepage.xml` but you have included layout `content_home_page` here

```
<include layout="@layout/content_home_page"/>
```

Change `content_home_page` to `content_of_homepage`